# I need to create multiple instances of my CSS class in js

Tags: javascript, css, toast

I have a base class called toast in CSS that includes all of my basic styling, with a javascript function that is passed a type of toast to create based on user input in order to give feedback. This function edits my toast class and adds in some icons and text as shown below:

```
#toast {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 40px;
        max-height: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        //and a whole bunch more styling
        }
```

And then my js:

```
function showToast(type) {
    var label = null;
    var iconElement = null;
    var i = document.getElementById("toast")

    switch (type) {
        case 'success':
            i.style.border = 'solid 1px #007700';
            label = "SUCCESS";
            iconElement = "icons/success.png";
            break;
           //and then a bunch more cases for my other types
    }

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = label;
    document.getElementById("icon").src = iconElement;
    i.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Currently every time I call my function to create a new toast it replaces the old one, however I would like to update them so they can stack and be able to output multiple pieces of feedback at once. How do I create multiple instances of my CSS class so that they are not overwritten every time I call my constructor?

Comment: Why don't you just make classes to augment your toast class, "toast success" for example

Comment: That would work as well, but I still have the same issue, say if I wanted to output two error toasts at the same time. I've made this for a validation page that will pop up with feedback for each section, so even if a user inputs multiple errors only one error feedback toast could appear at a time

Comment: start by using a class, not an id (classes start with a dot not a hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably giving every single element the ID, toast. Therefore, when you run this line (which is missing a semicolon (;)):

```
var i = document.getElementById("toast")
```

You're just getting the first element with the toast ID over and over again and replace it.

What you might want to do is assign a class to your toast element.

It might look something like this:

```
<div id="genericToast1" class="toast"></div>
<div id="successToast1" class="toast success"></div>
<div id="burntToast1" class="toast burnt"></div>
```

Then in your CSS, you can just use class selectors to modify them like this:

```
.toast 
{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    //and a whole bunch more styling
}

.toast.success
{
//More styling for this kind of toast...
}

.toast.burnt
{
//More styling...
}
```

No JS needed!

Comment: The reason I did it in my javascript is that most of what my functions do is text and icons, which I needed the js for anyways. Just made more sense to add a few styles through the js than to create entirely new subclasses for each type purely to house one or two style changes. However, I believe your first edit using the different div id's with the class they belong to will solve my problem

Comment: You are correct! You should change the way you're identifying your DOM elements, and you'll still be able to use your JS solution. I would just change your code to use the getElementsByClassName function. It returns an array of elements, so loop through that and then use some if statements to check for the other classes and add your css/icons that way. Good luck :)